# Retrieving training performance metrics from Tensorflow Estimator

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I have a basic tf TPUEstimator that I am using to train my neural network, it trains successfully and logs the decreasing Loss both in stdout logging as well as TensorBoard output log files.

However I am unable to find the `train_examples/sec` or `train_global_step/sec` metrics. I have `tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)` set, but these metrics do not show up in the console or Tensorboard.

Is there a LoggingHook I need to add when training? Alternatively, is there another way of measuring steps or examples per second as a metric?

Tensorflow Version is 1.14 and Python3.7

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting a very high value (or 0) for `log_step_count_steps` in the [tf.estimator.RunConfig](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/RunConfig#__init__)?
Alternatively, you can manually add a [tf.train.StepCounterHook](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.14/api_docs/python/tf/train/StepCounterHook).